# Clearance code while working with Promises

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am new to Nodejs and as well as async programming so I am trying to make shopping project I just want to clarify that even though my program works just fine but is my approach correct or not

controllers file

```
exports.posteditproduct = (req, res, next) => {
  const upprodid = req.body.productid;
  const upprodtitle = req.body.title;
  const upprodprice = req.body.price;
  const upprodimg = req.body.imageurl;
  const upproddesc = req.body.description;
  Product(
    upprodid,
    upprodtitle,
    upprodimg,
    upprodprice,
    upproddesc
  );

  Product.updateproduct(
    upprodid,
    upprodtitle,
    upprodprice,
    upprodimg,
    upproddesc
  ).then(function(value){
    console.log(value)
    fs.writeFile(p,JSON.stringify(value),err=>{
      console.log(err)
    })
  })
  res.redirect('/')
}
```

models

```
static updateproduct(
  upprodid,
  upprodtitle,
  upprodprice,
  upprodimg,
  upproddesc
) {
  const p = path.join(
    path.dirname(process.mainModule.filename),
    'data',
    'products.json'
  )

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.readFile(p, (err, data) => {
      const allproducts = JSON.parse(data)
      const existproductid = allproducts.findIndex(prod => prod.id === upprodid)
      const upproduct = [...allproducts]
      const spreadall = upproduct[existproductid]

      spreadall.id = upprodid
      spreadall.title = upprodtitle
      spreadall.imageurl = upprodimg
      spreadall.price = upprodprice
      spreadall.description = upproddesc
      upproduct[existproductid] = spreadall

      return resolve(upproduct)
    })
  })
}
```

So is it okay if in my models file I do all the stuff and then return the final variable within the resolve ( ) and then in my controllers file I just use

```
.then(function(value) {
  //and then write in file here
})
```

Would this approach be okay if I have a very large file with n no. of entries ?
Or should I write the writeFile method too inside the Promise in the updateproduct method?

Comment: Hi, perhaps do the I/O within the async function?

Comment: can you work on your code formatting its hard to read?

Comment: @Xesenix is it okay now ?

Comment: @jspcal well does it really matter ? i mean any issue while using Promises ?

Comment: looks more readable still some place for improvement but now maybe more people will be able to check it out

Comment: so I thought a little bit about this and for really large files you would have to use [streams](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html) and if you wonder if part of code that is inside then is done in async way the answer is yes but that doesn't mean a separate process is handling it async in javascript is still done on one process and only one thing can be done in the same time. You may want to research [workers](https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html)

Comment: @Xesenix ok thanks for d advice

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195392/discussion-between-xesenix-and-ratnabh-kumar-rai).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it´s about code review and should be posted here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/